# HTML Select Tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to alert the value of a specific option in my dropdown when it is clicked. Here is my code:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    alert($("option").html());
});
```

I've tried using `.text()` and `.val()`, but neither seems to work.

Comment: `alert(this.value);`

Comment: Please include the relevant html (it would be great if you made this into a code snippet).  `$("option")` gets every option tag.  I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: "a specific option" How is the option specified? Is it the selected option or some other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not using a `select[multiple]` element, "The jQuery Way™" to get the value is:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

which really might as well be:

```
console.log(this.value);
```

---

The problem with your existing code is that `$('option')` selects all `option` elements, and then `.html()` gets the innerHTML of the first `option` element in the collection.

You don't want the first `option` on the page, you want the current value of the `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).val());
```

This should work i guess, if you want the value and not the text

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough

```
$("select").change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```